# Python Removing the first line of 2 CSV file and save them as in the same file

Tags: python, csv

Please help with the bellow code, its for reading 2 CSV files and removing their first row. The problem is that It saves them in another CSV files and they both are identical. I need to save them in the same original file.

```
import time
import os
import os, re
import logging
import glob
import csv


for CSV1 in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads'):
   if re.match('XXXcsv', CSV1):
       print(CSV1)
#remove the first 5 rows in the CSV file
with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\' + CSV1,'r') as f:
    with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\P6CB.csv','w') as f1:
        next(f) # skip header line
        for line1 in f:
            f1.write(line1)


for CSV2 in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads'):
   if re.match('VVVcsv', CSV2):
       print(CSV2)
#remove the first 5 rows in the CSV file
with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\' + CSV2,'r') as v:
    with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\WindowsDevices.csv','w') as v1:
        next(v) # skip header line
        next(v) # skip header line
        next(v) # skip header line
        next(v) # skip header line
        next(v) # skip header line
        for line2 in v:
            v1.write(line2)
```

Update: I cound delete the first row of the CSV sheets and save it as new sheet. Now i need to combain them. Updated Code:

```
import time
import os
import os, re
import logging
import glob

import csv


for CSV in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads'):
    if re.match('Phase_6_Chromebooks', CSV):
        print(CSV)
        CSV1 = CSV

#remove the first 5 rows in the CSV file
with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\' + CSV1,'r') as f:
    with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\P6CB.csv','w') as f1:
        next(f) # skip header line
        next(f) # skip header line
        next(f) # skip header line
        next(f) # skip header line
        next(f) # skip header line
        for line1 in f:
            f1.write(line1)


for CSV in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads'):
    if re.match('Windows_Devices', CSV):
        print(CSV)
        CSV2 = CSV

#remove the first 5 rows in the CSV file
with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\' + CSV2,'r') as v:
    with open('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\WindowsDevices.csv','w') as v1:
         next(v) # skip header line
         next(v) # skip header line
         next(v) # skip header line
         next(v) # skip header line
         next(v) # skip header line
         for line2 in v:
             v1.write(line2)

for CSV in os.listdir('C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads'):
    if re.match('Phase_4_Chromebooks', CSV):
        print(CSV)
        CSV3 = CSV

csv_files = ['C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\' + CSV3 , 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\P6CB.csv' , 'C:\\Users\\XXXXX\\Downloads\\WindowsDevices.csv']
```

Comment: open file for reading, read relevant lines to memory, close the file, open the file for writing, write the relevant line. Or use temporary file and then copy/move it to be the original file if the file is too large to be read into memory

Comment: write to new files then delete old files. is there any reason why do you want to write to same file?